# Where does the noise in ToString("G51") come from?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, pi

If you evaluate

```
(Math.PI).ToString("G51")
```

the result is

```
"3,141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875"
```

`Math.Pi` is correct up to the 15th decimal which is in accordance with the precision of a `double`. "G17" is used for round tripping, so I expected the `ToString` to stop after "G17", but instead it continued to produce numbers up to "G51".

**Q** Since the digits after 15th decimal are beyond the precision afforded by the 53 bits of mantissa, how are the remaining digits calculated?

Comment: See https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Please write the result of 1/3 in base 10. Hint: you can't. You can only write combinations of powers of 10 (e.g. 10^-1 (aka 0.1), 2*10^-1 (0.2), 10^-2 (0.01), etc. So 0.23 is possible, but 1/3 isn't 0.333, and not even 0.334, at least not exactly. Likewise with binary you can only use combinations of powers of 2.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, @Richard That's not my point. A double has a 53 bit mantissa which corresponds to 15 decimals. So where does the noise after the 17th decimal come from? Does `ToString("G51")` make them up?

Comment: I have voted to reopen. There are many answers in the proposed dup but I don't think any of them directly address this question. Note that the decimal digits appears to be simply the exact base 10 value of the approximated double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A double has a 53 bit mantissa which corresponds to 15 decimals

A double has a 53 bit mantissa which corresponds to *roughly* 15 decimals.

Math.Pi is truncated at 53 bits in binary, which is not precisely equal to

3.1415926535897

but it's also not quite equal to

3.14159265358979

, etc.

Just like 1/3 is not quite 0.3, or 0.33, etc.

If you continue the decimal expansion long enough it will eventually terminate or start repeating, since Math.PI, unlike π is a rational number.

And as you can verify with a [BigRational](https://c-ohle.github.io/RationalNumerics/index.html) type

```
using System.Numerics;

var r = new BigRational(Math.PI);
BigRational dem;

BigRational.NumDen(r, out dem);
var num = r * dem;

Console.WriteLine(num);
Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
Console.WriteLine(dem);
```

it's

```
884279719003555
---------------
281474976710656
```

And since the denominator is a power of 2 (which it has to be since Math.PI has a binary mantissa and so a terminating representation in base-2).  It also therefore has a terminating representation in base-10, which is exactly what was given by `(Math.PI).ToString("G51")`:

3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

as

```
Console.WriteLine(r == BigRational.Parse("3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875"));
```

outputs

```
True
```

Comment: the exact value of 884279719003555/281474976710656 is [3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=884279719003555%2F281474976710656)

Answer (score 0):

The `.ToString("G51")` method uses 'school math'. First it takes the integer part, then it multiplies the `Remainder` by 10, use the integer part of that calculation and multiplies the `Remainder` part by 10.

It will keep doing that as long as there is a remainder and up to `51` decimal digits.

Since `double` has an exponent, it will keep having a remainder with about 18 decimal digits, which produces the next digit in `ToString` method.

However, as you have seen, the `Remainder` part is not accurate but simply a result of a math function.